# How do I get the correct DOM elements with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the text in a sibling span element and the name of a parent div when the user clicks on an "a" element that will be repeated hundreds of times. (In the example below I just include two but you get the idea.) See my code below and please help me understand how to name them at the spot marked with comments. Both javascript and jQuery are available to solve the problem.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="div001">
      <a href="javascript:{}" class="citation"><span class="book">Book 1</span> <span class="month">January</span></a>
    </div>
    <div id="output001"></div>

    <div id="div002">
      <a href="javascript:{}" class="citation"><span class="book">Book 2</span> <span class="month">February</span></a>
    </div>
    <div id="output002"></div>

    <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j( ".citation" ).click(function ( )
      {
        event.preventDefault();

        var book = ???;     // <==== How do I capture “Book 1” or “Book 2”?
        var divName = ???;  // <==== How do I capture “div001” or “div002”?

        $j('#' + divName.replace('div', 'output')).html(book);
      }); 
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are these elements created? dynamically?

Comment: Ultimately, yes. If you have suggestions for a better structure I am open to it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Um, it's right there in black and white with full code and, literally, arrows. Other people got it and answered quite quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question might have dozens of answers, but here is just one of them:

```
 $j(document).on("click", ".citation", function ( ){
   var book = $(this).find('span.book').html();
   var divName = $(this).parent().attr('id');
 }
```

Note that since your elements are created dynamically you should use `.on()`.

Comment: I need to make $ into $j to match my code but yes, this is the answer.

Comment: @KennethVogt I updated it, could you please mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: The system makes me wait 5 minutes first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 var book = $(">span.book", this).html();
 var divName = $(this).closest("div").prop('id');
```

Comment: Javascript is maddening/amazing that it allows you to solve problems in multiple ways...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/civizugene/1/edit?html,css,console,output

You can use jQuery find() to find elements by class or type.